# Mocking chained methods calls using PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a class which I would like to test with a public static method that contains some chained method calls. Assuming that an exception occurs during the chained method calls, how do I handle this effectively and make it return some specific value?

**Following is the code sample of the test class.**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({CodeWithPrivateMethod.class,CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.class,CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod.class})
public class CodeWithPrivateMethodTest {

@Test
public void when_gambling_is_true_then_always_explode() throws Exception {


    CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod codeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod = PowerMockito.spy(new CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod());
    PowerMockito.whenNew(CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(codeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod);

    CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod = PowerMockito.spy(new CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod());
    PowerMockito.whenNew(CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod);

    PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(codeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod, "getGambling");

    //PowerMockito.doReturn(codeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod).when(codeWithAnotherPrivateMethod, "getGambleValue");

    PowerMockito.spy(CodeWithPrivateMethod.class);
    CodeWithPrivateMethod.startGamble();

    }

}
```

**Following is the code sample for the class under test**

```
public class CodeWithPrivateMethod {

public static void startGamble() {

    Boolean gamble = CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.getGambleValue()
            .getGambling();
    if (gamble) {
        System.out.println("kaboom");
    }else{
        System.out.println("boom boom");
    }
    }
}
```

**Following is the code sample for the class that gets called from the class under test**

```
public class CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod {

static CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod codeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod = new CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod();


public static CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod getGambleValue() {
    return codeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod; //works fine
    return null; // fails
    }
}
```

**Following is the code sample for the other class that gets called from the class under test**

```
public class CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod {

public Boolean getGambling() {
    return false;
    }
}
```

So Assuming I return a null value from getGambleValue() method of CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod class, how do I handle this null value effectively in my testclass?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to specify expected exceptions using Mockito:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void when_gambling_is_true_then_always_explode() throws Exception {
    ...
```

Before I found out about this I would do:

```
@Test
public void when_gambling_is_true_then_always_explode() throws Exception {
    // setup omitted
    try {
        CodeWithPrivateMethod.startGamble();
    } 
    catch(NullPointerException e) {
        // expected
        return;
    }
    fail("Expected NullPointerException");
}
```

EDIT: Testing multiple classes that call each other statically like this is a severe code smell. Unit tests should test a single class and inline static calls should be limited to utility classes.

Another comment: your example class names are very confusing. Next time please stick with Foo, Bar, Baz or Appple, Pear, Banana.

If you are not getting an NPE then I expect your mocking/spying is interfering. If you call the code under test without mocking/spying the call chain would be:

```
CodeWithPrivateMethod.startGamble();
->
CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod value = CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.getGambleValue();
-> 
return null;
<-
value.getGambling();
<- throws NullPointerException
```

What exactly are you trying to find out or achieve?

EDIT: Here's how it should work with PowerMock

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.class)
public class CodeWithPrivateMethodTest {

  @Mock
  private CodeWithYetAnotherPrivateMethod yetAnotherInstance;

  @Test
  public final void testStartGamble() {

    // SETUP
    mockStatic(CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.class);
    expect(CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.getGambleValue())
        .andReturn(yetAnotherInstance);
    Boolean gamblingValue = true;
    expect(yetAnotherInstance.getGambling()).andReturn(gamblingValue);
    replayAll();

    // CALL
    CodeWithPrivateMethod.startGamble();

    // VERIFY
    verifyAll();
  }
```

Comment: yes I am aware of that fact but it results in test case throwing java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception:java.lang.NullPointerException. So probably that isn't the right way to handle it?

Comment: Sorry about the class names, i will take care next time. That said i want to test whether startGamble() method functions correctly. And as CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.getGambleValue() ------> _returns null_, obviously a NullPointerException is thrown when getGambling() is called. So my question is how do i mock  **CodeWithAnotherPrivateMethod.getGambleValue()
            .getGambling()** to return either true/false

Comment: Is any of this code modifiable by you? My first instinct would be to get rid of all this static chaining.